# Print the data that matches to the condition in log file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, logging, awk

`log.txt` as below, the data is in a set contain ID, detection_time, Age and Height.
My first part is to print the ID that appears again in the `log.txt` within 15 sec from its first appearance by using shell script which i've done it already. The second part is to print "detection_time", "Age" "Height" of the ID that match to my condition will also be printed with the ID too.
The second part is where im stucked because i don't know how to develop the programming algorithm.

```
ID = 4231
detection_time = 1595556730 
Age = 25
Height = 182
ID = 3661
detection_time = 1595556737
Age = 24
Height = 182
ID = 2654
detection_time = 1595556740
Age = 22
Height = 184    
ID = 3661
detection_time = 1595556746
Age = 27
Height = 175
ID = 4231
detection_time = 1595556752
Age = 25
```

For example, log from above, the ID 3661 first appear at time 1595556737 and then appear again at 1595556746 which is just 9 sec after the first appearance. So it is matched to my condition which is want the ID that appear again within 15sec. After run a shell script, my desired output will be ID`3661` with its latest `detection_time` `Age` and `Height` data of this ID 3661 which are

```
the matched ID is 3661
detection_time = 1595556746
Age = 27
Height = 175
```

Here is my code. I use associative array `arr` where id  as key and detection_time as value. After run this script where above logfile as an input. The output will be `The matched ID is 3661` without the ID detection_time, Age and Height which is where im stucked. Can anyone help me with this? Thank you.

```
#!/bin/bash
input="/tmp/log.txt"
declare -A arr
while read -r line
do

if [[ $line =~ ID ]] ; then
 id=$(echo $line | awk -F " " '{print $3}')
elif [[ $line =~ detection_time ]] ; then
 dtime=$(echo $line | awk -F " " '{print $3}')
 if  [[ arr["$id"] -ge $((dtime - 15)) ]]; then
  echo 'The matched ID is' "$id"
 fi
 arr["$id"]=$dtime
fi
done < "$input"
```

Comment: If have not understood completely what you want, but at least I can give you some hint with parsing a line: `if [[ $line =~ ^ID[[:space:]]=[[:space:]]([[:digit:]]+)$ ]]; then` this will put the `id` in `${BASH_REMATCH[1]}` and removes the need to use `awk` for this.

Comment: See also this earlier question by the same OP https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63228001/extract-the-unpredictable-data-that-have-its-own-timestamp-in-a-log-file-using-a

Comment: Don't use a shell loop for this, see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)

Answer (score 3):

This task fits to `awk`. Script below will print all cases where some id reappears in `<=` 15 seconds from its last detection.

file `tst.awk` :

```
$1=="ID" { if (p) print(rec); p=0; rec=""; id=$NF }
$1=="detection_time" { if ($NF - t[id] <= 15) p=1; t[id]=$NF }
{ rec = (rec? rec RS $0: $0) }
END { if (p) print(rec) }
```

Usage:

```
> awk -f tst.awk file
ID = 3661
detection_time = 1595556746
Age = 27
Height = 175
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is exactly what you expect as output.

```
#!/bin/bash
input="/tmp/log.txt"
declare -A arr
mode=""
while read -r line
do

if [[ $line =~ ^ID[[:space:]]=[[:space:]]([[:digit:]]+)$ ]] ; then
 id=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
 [ -n "${mode}" ] && printf "\n"
elif [[ $line =~ ^(Age|Height)[[:space:]]=[[:space:]]([[:digit:]]+)$ ]] && [ -n "${mode}" ]; then
 printf "and %s is %s " "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
elif [[ $line =~ ^detection_time[[:space:]]=[[:space:]]([[:digit:]]+)$ ]] ; then
 dtime=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
 if  [[ arr["$id"] -ge $((dtime - 15)) ]]; then
  printf 'The matched ID is %d at first time: %s ' "$id" "$( date -Iseconds -d @${arr[${id}]} )"
  mode="1"
 else
  mode=""
 fi
 arr["$id"]=$dtime
fi
done < "$input"
```

This prints the following from your input:

```
The matched ID is 3661 at first time: 2020-07-24T04:12:17+02:00 and Age is 27 and Height is 175
```

Hope this helps you to make it like you need it.